# How do I set the dimensions of Conv1d correctly?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

This is a toy example as I'm learning PyTorch and using it on one-dimensional time series, in this case a sine wave.

I'm trying to use Conv1d, but I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [5, 1, 2], expected input[1, 994, 5] to have 1 channels, but got 994 channels instead
```

My 'lookback' is 5 time steps, and the shape of my data batch is `[994, 5]`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import torch;from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F;import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch import nn, tensor

class TsDs(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, s, l=5): super().__init__();self.l,self.s=l,s
  def __len__(self): return self.s.shape[0] - 1 - self.l
  def __getitem__(self, i): return self.s[i:i+self.l], torch.log(self.s[i+self.l+1]/self.s[i+self.l])
  def plt(self): plt.plot(self.s)

class TsDm(pl.LightningDataModule):
  def __init__(self, length=5000, batch_size=1000): super().__init__();self.batch_size=batch_size;self.s = torch.sin(torch.arange(length)*0.2) + 5
  def train_dataloader(self): return DataLoader(TsDs(self.s[:3999]), batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=False)
  def val_dataloader(self): return DataLoader(TsDs(self.s[4000:]), batch_size=self.batch_size)

dm = TsDm()

class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01):
        super().__init__();self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        super().__init__();self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.network = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv1d(1,5,2),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(5,3),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(3,1), nn.Tanh())
        # self.network = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5,5),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(5,3),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(3,1), nn.Tanh())
    def forward(self, x): return self.network(x)
    def step(self, batch, batch_idx, stage):
        x, y = batch
        loss = -torch.mean(self(x)*y)
        print(loss)
        return loss
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx): return self.step(batch, batch_idx, "train")
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx): return self.step(batch, batch_idx, "val")
    def configure_optimizers(self): return torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)

mm = MyModel(0.01);trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10)
trainer.fit(mm, datamodule=dm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Looking at the documentation of [`nn.Conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html), your input shape should be `(B, C, L)`. In your default case, you have `L=5`, the sequence length, but you need to create that extra dimension representing the feature size of a sequence element, here `C=1`. You can do so by changing `TsDs`'s  `__getitem__` function to:

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, i):
       x = self.s[i:i+self.l] # minibatch x shaped (1, self.l)
       y = torch.log(self.s[i+self.l+1]/self.s[i+self.l]) # minibatch y shaped (1,)
       return x, y
   ```
2. Your convolutional layer has a stride of `1` and a size of `2`, this means its output will be shaped `(B, 5, L-1=4)`. The following layer is a fully connected layer instantiated as `nn.Linear(5, 3)`, which means it expects `(*, H_in=5)` and will output `(*, H_out)`. You can either

   - You can flatten the *conv1d* output with [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) and feed it to a bigger fully connected layer (for instance `nn.Linear(20, 3)`.
   - You can use a convolutional layer with a wider kernel, if you use a kernel of `5` (your sequence length you will end up with a tensor of `(B, 5, 1)` which you feed to a `nn.Linear(5, 3)`. Although this approach doesn't really scale when `L` is changed.
   - You could apply a [`nn.AvgPool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool1d.html) to get an average representation of the sequence after the convolutional layers have been applied.

   Those are just a few directions...

Comment: This is really useful, thank you! It's my first time working with PyTorch. I'm guessing it's normal practice to have to reshape the arrays between layers?

Comment: Most often, you will have to resort to some kind of flattening operation. For example, when working with CNN coupled with classifiers, you will have to flatten the extra dimensions together in order to work with fully connected nets. It all depends on your architecture and the intent you have behind the design.